# Checkout Document from Alfresco using DotCMIS

Tags: alfresco, cmis, dotcmis

How can i checkout a document from Alfresco using dotCMIS?

Answer (score 4):

It's in the `IDocument` interface:

```
IObjectId id = session.CreateObjectId("12345678");
IDocument doc = session.GetObject(id) as IDocument;
IDocument checkedOutDoc = doc.CheckOut() as IDocument;
```

Comment: i get the following error :DotCMIS.Exceptions.CmisInvalidArgumentException: Bad Request

Comment: are you sure you're using an id to a document (`cm:content` in Alfresco) when calling `CreateObjectId`?

Comment: how can i get the id of a document? I am new to alfresco and cmis

Comment: from Alfresco Share, when you look at the details page of a document you can take the value of the `nodeRef` parameter in the URL (e.g. `http://alfresco.host:8080/share/page/document-details?nodeRef=workspace://SpacesStore/38dee96f-e028-4bed-821f-0ed25cc2ba07`). From the Alfresco Explorer, the document details page has an "Alfresco Node Reference" link.

Comment: got that. But how can i open the file in my client application?

Comment: you need to get the content stream: `IContentStream contentStream = doc.GetContentStream();`. I strongly suggest you to read more on [CMIS](http://www.optaros.com/blogs/new-tutorial-getting-started-with-cmis) before continuing your development.

Comment: @user673453: You should accept this answer if it is a solution to the question you asked originally.